# Autocomplete radius search not working in my google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to implement radius on my gmaps Autocomplete place search,so i can get search hint from that radius first.

**my code**

```
var options = {
        types: [],
        componentRestrictions: {
            'country': 'IN'
        },
        location : { lat: 17.3850, lng: 78.4867 },
        radius : 5000
    };
    let inputPick = document.getElementById('pick');
    const autocompletePick = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputPick, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocompletePick, 'place_changed',  () => {
        let place =autocompletePick.getPlace();
        // console.log(place.name)
        // document.getElementById('pick').value = place.name;
        this.setState({pickAddress:place.name})
        let lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
            lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        //putting place in pick field
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocoder.geocode({'location': {lat:lat,lng:lng}}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                // console.log(results[0].formatted_address)
                document.getElementById('pick').value = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
        })
```

**but right now i'm getting all over country place**.
i search on google but didn't get proper solution.can anyone help me,i''m stuck ):

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Google Maps JavaScript API reference documentation, you will see that `AutocompleteOptions` object doesn't have `location` and `radius` fields

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#AutocompleteOptions

Instead it has `bounds` field to define an area where you would like to search and `strictBounds` field to restrict results to this area only.

You should rewrite your code with `bounds` and `strictBounds` autocomplete options. Something like

```
var options = {
    bounds: cityBounds,
    strictBounds: true,
    types: ['geocode'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: "IN" }
};
```

Have a look at bounds documentation for more details

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBounds

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#LatLngBoundsLiteral

I hope this helps!